# cURL 28 error after switch from to brew php 7.2 on localhost

Tags: php, rest-api, updates, apache, curl

I've been running into trouble with all my localhost install of Wordpress reporting cURL error 28 (timeout) since (*I believe!*)I've switched my PHP version from 7.0 to 7.2 with brew on my local Mac OS machine. Viewing any of my local site’s admin areas or using the WP CLI the WP update checks and other cURL calls result in failing cURL requests:

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not
>   establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your
>   server administrator.) in /Users/…/wp-includes/update.php on line xxx

*(xxx line varies on which install, local https site or not, etc, but always boils down to a line catching a curl error)*

From what I can tell PHP is using the brew installed cURL and cURL works both in CLI and in PHP, e.g. running this explicitly in a theme functions.php works and returns the expected result (a JSON of updates):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
var_dump("exec", curl_exec($ch));
var_dump("error", curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

Equally, just getting a cURL request on the terminal works as well:

```
curl -v http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/
```

Both return the same JSON.

I've tried to edit my WP’s `/wp-includes/` various http, request and cURL related classes to debug what is going on. Since the functios.php’s cURL works, but WP’s internal do not, I assume my PHP cURL is working per se.

In `/wp-includes/Requests/Transports/cURL.php` I've tried to comment out as many `curl_setopt` calls as possible to approximate the same minimal cURL call that works in my functions.php but with no luck — also I don't know of a way to see the exact cURL settings the request goes out with. `curl_getinfo` reveals mostly empty or defaulted values, like what I'd expect with a request that never succeeded.

Other things I've tried and checked:

- Installed Health Check plugin to confirm: Yes, REST API fails, Connection to Wordpress.org fails, Loopback request fails
- Various combinations of: Disabled plugins & themes, no plugins, fresh WP install
- phpinfo() tells me cURL is enabled (v7.64.0)
- I reinstalled curl, openssh, php@7.2 via brew several times
- Restarted computer, restarted apache server
- Posted on [wp.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/curl-error-28-on-localhost-updates/)
- Checked php error log, checked WP debug.log, set error_reporting to (E_ALL): Nothing suspicious in regards to cURL calls shows up
- Firewall is disabled (also the other cURL calls work, so…)

I'm absolutely baffled about what is going on here and why WP’s cURL requests are failing and essentially rendering my entire development environment useless.

Any help or suggestions to get to the bottom of this is very, very much appreciated.

Edit: FYI, same issue on stackoverflow as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906545/how-to-set-or-circumvent-curlopt-connecttimeout-in-php-globally

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.samuelaguilera.com/post/curl-error-28-wordpress

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Had seen it, yes, but that didn't apply to a case where a cURL would normally work, but not from within WP’s internals.

Comment: You don't happen to have `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL` set, do you? Since it's an issue with resolving, could you try curling the IP for api.wordpress.org instead of the domain name. Also, try setting `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` to 30 seconds or longer.

Comment: I don't have `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL` set and am also trying this form different local installations. Curl’ing the IP I get a 302 because it seems to fetch from wordpress.org not api.wordpress.org, but I think this can be expected. Increasing the timeout, via filter, constants or directly in WP core classes does not have any other effect except it taking longer to timeout; it’s not an issue with an actual timeout, I reckon, just that the timeout is the final trigger for aborting the cURL that is set to fail from the beginning.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett You were spot on about `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`, actually! I've looked at the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` option all the time, changing it’s values, but bumping `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` actually resolves the issue, partially. The problem is a) I don't know what changed in my PHP upgrade that the behavior in this regard is different now, and b) I don't know how to set this aside from the `http_api_curl` — for example my WP CLI calls still fail, because they use the 10s default defined in `/wp-includes/class-request.php`.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906545/how-to-set-or-circumvent-curlopt-connecttimeout-in-php-globally

Comment: This has been in the back of my mind. It might be time to go all the way to the source. The Requests library powers all this. http://requests.ryanmccue.info/docs/usage.html You can find it in `wp-includes/Requests`. I would try making a request using this library and making use of the exceptions built in.

Comment: @kontur What's your OS? If macos or linux, when you type `which php` what's the output? Also, if macos or linux, what do you have inside your file `/etc/hosts`? And what's your local WP installation URL?

Comment: @filipecsweb `$ which php` gives the expected `/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php`, `$ php --version` is `PHP 7.2.15 (cli)` which also matches the output from `phpinfo()` which is `PHP Version 7.2.15` — all on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3. My `/etc/hosts` has my various localhost setups, most of which have a custom vhost, but I also have some match all vhosts matches to my ~/Sites directory.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett I've already narrowed down that it is the cURL call itself and the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` in particular that is crucial, not the wrapper around it. Not sure how using the library separate of WP will help?

Comment: @kontur Sorry, didn't see your other comment. If the problem is with the time it takes to resolve, that should be an issue with your connection or DNS. Have you tried switching to another DNS provider that's local? Google and Cloudflare both have services you could try for free to test.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Not sure how to do that, exactly, but I can inquire. But would you say if my DNS provider is dynamic, it would be different for my a) work, b) home, and c) when tethering 4G from my phone — in which case it’s a non option, since in all locations the same result persists.

Comment: If it's happening in multiple locations, it's more unlikely that the issue is with a particular DNS provider. John B's answer mentions DNS caching which sounds probable to me as well.

Comment: So... the answer was "change your DNS servers"?

Comment: @MikeNGarrett As silly as it seems, yes. I just have had no reason to suspect any change had happens so it didn’t seem a likely source to inspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Try This First: Your Problem Might Be DNS

**In my testing this is a problem with DNS resolving**. In my case it's because the DNS filter/cache I run on my local network wasn't responding to requests. After restarting the service on the DNS server my requests got through quickly & easily. I would suggest checking any local DNS servers on your network.

OP also resolved the problem by specifically changing DNS settings to Google's DNS provider, but I saw elsewhere that for some problem the problem was Google's DNS, so switching away from Google fixed the problem.

---

### Back to your regularly scheduled answer:

<s>If it's a CURL_CONNECTTIMEOUT problem, then you I *think* you can do this:</s>

```
function filter_request_timeout($timeout) {
    return 100; // desired time in seconds
}
add_filter('http_request_timeout', 'filter_request_timeout' );
```

Both `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` use the same value when the timeout is set: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-http-curl.php#L127

However, if this just happened since installing PHP 7.2 maybe there's another reason. Did you update the cURL extension as well? I'm having the same issue on PHP 7.3 via Homebrew, so I'm going to see what I can do without resorting to adding a filter to the dev version of all my sites.

**Update:** the `http_request_timeout` filter is for the *default* timeout. If the timeout has been set between getting the default and sending the request, it needs to happen in the `http_request_args` filter:

```
function johnbeales_filter_request_args( $args, $url ) {

    if(strpos($url, 'wordpress.org') !== false ) {
        $args['timeout'] = 100; // Timeout in seconds
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter('http_request_args', 'johnbeales_filter_request_args', 10, 2);
```

Since we're having trouble connecting to wordpress.org, I only adjusted the timeout on requests to wordpress.org.

Comment: Hey @"John B", thanks for your answer! I've managed to use a filter to overwrite the WP curl request settings, but the problem is that a) I'd need to do this for every localhost install I have (10~20 active at any point) and b) the filters only affect parts that load the theme functions — e.g. the WP CLI calls will still fail.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal, and weird. With me, when I set a 100-second timeout, sometimes my whole browser request timed out and I just got a 503, (IIRC). Once I fixed the DNS it was super-fast.  I saw somewhere that there might be a problem with Google DNS and those WordPress.org URLs, so if you're using Google DNS maybe try Cloudflare and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Well, this is astonishing. Explicitly added e.g. Google’s DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4) and the cURL connection requests no longer time out. I think you ought to highlight that in your answer, since that is essentially what solved the problem; not using my default DNS servers in my MacOS network settings. Probably I thought the PHP update introduced the issue, but I remember I updated PHP because I had updated MacOS — so maybe that update changed or reset some network settings.

Comment: @kontur Done! Hopefully anyone else can fix this more easily than we did ;)